# How to pivot a table using a sequence of quarters between two dates

Tags: r, reshape, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame with two date columns (from and to). I'd like to create a year and quarter sequence between the two dates and then reshape to transform to a tall data frame.

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, from = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2018-01-01", "2018-04-01"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("2018-02-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-10-01"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> df
id      from        to
1       2018-01-01  2018-04-01
2       2018-01-01  2018-02-01
3       2018-04-01  2018-10-01
4       2018-04-01  2018-07-01
```

In the example above id 1 is in Q1 and Q2 whereas id 2 is only in Q1.

Desired output:

```
#id Quarter
#1  Q1 2018
#1  Q2 2018
#2  Q1 2018
#3  Q2 2018
#3  Q3 2018
#3  Q4 2018
#4  Q2 2018
#4  Q3 2018
```

I'm able to get a quarter sequence using seq function:

```
dsq <- seq(ymd('2018-01-01'),ymd('2018-04-01'), by = 'quarters')
paste0("Q", lapply(dsq, quarter), " ", lapply(dsq, year))
```

but I'm looking for a way to reshape my table using the obtained sequence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(2:3, zoo::as.yearqtr, format = "%Y-%m-%d") %>% 
  gather(key, Quarter, -id) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  arrange(id)
#  id Quarter
#1  1 2018 Q1
#2  1 2018 Q2
#3  2 2018 Q1
#4  2 2018 Q1
#5  3 2018 Q2
#6  3 2018 Q4
#7  4 2018 Q2
#8  4 2018 Q3
```

---

Or try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=`(from = as.Date(from),
                 to = as.Date(to))
          ][, .(Quarter = as.yearqtr(seq(from, to, "quarter"))), by = id]
```

If `from` and `to` are already of class `date`, then this simplifies to

```
setDT(df)[, .(Quarter = as.yearqtr(seq(from, to, "quarter"))), by = id]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a little extra to your code :

```
f <- function(x,y) {
  dsq <- seq(ymd(x),ymd(y), by = 'quarters')
  paste0("Q", lapply(dsq, quarter), " ", lapply(dsq, year))
}

df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(quarter=list(f(from,to))) %>% unnest
## A tibble: 8 x 4
#     id from       to         quarter      
#  <int> <fct>      <fct>      <chr>  
#1     1 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 Q1 2018
#2     1 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 Q2 2018
#3     2 2018-01-01 2018-02-01 Q1 2018
#4     3 2018-04-01 2018-10-01 Q2 2018
#5     3 2018-04-01 2018-10-01 Q3 2018
#6     3 2018-04-01 2018-10-01 Q4 2018
#7     4 2018-04-01 2018-07-01 Q2 2018
#8     4 2018-04-01 2018-07-01 Q3 2018
```